# Is it possible to use template tags in ValidationError's strings?

Tags: python, django, validation, django-templates, django-forms

I need to throw ValidationError containing anchor.

```
if not profile.activated():
    raise ValidationError('Your profile is not activated. <a href="{% url resend_activation_key %}">Resend activation key</a>.')
```

What I need to modify to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you want to use a template tag here? Template tags are for use in templates. If you want to find a reverse URL, use the [`reverse`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/http/urls/#reverse) function.

Answer (score 0):

First: just don't do this! Put HTML code where it belongs: into the template.

Second: you might be able to do this with

```
from django.template import Context, Template
t = Template(u"Your profile is not.... {% url blah %} ...")
raise ValidationError( t.render(Context())
```

But html tags will be escaped unless you mark them as safe in your template.

Comment: First note is sound. But how can I do this? Maybe by setting special form attribute?

Comment: Isn't it possible for you to check the profile activation before you show the form at all?
something like in your view:   if request.method == "GET" and not profile.activated(): redirect_to_url_describing_problem